# ogr2ogr sql query from dbf

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr

In ogr2ogr, I can successfully read *.DBF files and write them to PostgreSQL DB:

```
SET DBCONNECT=host=bla port=blue dbname=blub user=me password=easy active_schema=now
SET PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8
SET SOURCE=\\fileserver\test\ 
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"%DBCONNECT%" %SOURCE%DBF\countries.DBF  --config SHAPE_ENCODING "CP850" -overwrite
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"%DBCONNECT%" %SOURCE%DBF\taxes.DBF  --config SHAPE_ENCODING "CP850" -overwrite
SET PGCLIENTENCODING=LATIN1
```

However, I'm trying to find a simple solution to create (and update) an additional table in the same schema that logs the following values:

1. file found or not
2. Data directory
3. username of import
4. Date of import
5. modification date of the specific file

As I am pretty new to ogr2ogr.

Comment: Make a script that writes those 5 fields into a temporary .csv file, then convert csv into PostGIS.